# How to send packet through ppp link by Scapy

Tags: scapy, ppp

I'm trying to send packets through ppp link (created by wvdial connecting a 3g modem) but failing so far. Here is my 'ip addr' printout:

> ```
> 22: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 3
>     link/ppp
>     inet 10.40.43.62 peer 10.64.64.64/32 scope global ppp0
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever*
> ```

And this is how i'm trying to send by Scapy:

```
[root@server1 ~]# scapy
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
INFO: Can't import python ecdsa lib. Disabled certificate manipulation tools
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
>>> pkt=PPP()/IP(src="10.40.43.62", dst="8.8.8.8")/ICMP()/"1234567890"
>>> pkt.show()
###[ PPP Link Layer ]###
  proto= Internet Protocol version 4
###[ IP ]###
     version= 4
     ihl= None
     tos= 0x0
     len= None
     id= 1
     flags=
     frag= 0
     ttl= 64
     proto= icmp
     chksum= None
     src= 10.40.43.62
     dst= 8.8.8.8
     \options\
###[ ICMP ]###
        type= echo-request
        code= 0
        chksum= None
        id= 0x0
        seq= 0x0
###[ Raw ]###
           load= '1234567890'

>>> sendp(pkt, iface="ppp0")
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>> quit()
```

packet capture is showing Ethernet layer is getting added:

```
[root@server1 ~]# tshark -V -i ppp0 
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous. Capturing on 'ppp0' Frame 1: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0
    Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture (25)
    Arrival Time: Jan 29, 2018 10:54:20.793541000 BDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1517201660.793541000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 56 bytes (448 bits)
    Capture Length: 56 bytes (448 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: sll:eth:data] Linux cooked capture
    Packet type: Sent by us (4)
    Link-layer address type: 512
    Link-layer address length: 0
    Protocol: Ethernet (0x0003) Ethernet II, Src: EquipTra_00:40:01 (00:01:00:00:40:01), Dst: Semptian_00:00:26 (00:21:45:00:00:26)
    Destination: Semptian_00:00:26 (00:21:45:00:00:26)
        Address: Semptian_00:00:26 (00:21:45:00:00:26)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: EquipTra_00:40:01 (00:01:00:00:40:01)
        Address: EquipTra_00:40:01 (00:01:00:00:40:01)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: Unknown (0x3561) Data (26 bytes)

0000  0a 28 2b 3e 08 08 08 08 08 00 ed fa 00 00 00 00   .(+>............ 0010  31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30                   1234567890
    Data: 0a282b3e080808080800edfa000000003132333435363738...
    [Length: 26]
```

is send/sendp/sr are right command for this, what i am missing here? i can send ping through the ppp interface and in the packet capture it shows as ppp link layer.

this is the packet capture of scapy crafted packet and normal ICMP packet from ping tool

Normal:

```
12 <packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="100">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="13" showname="Number" value="d" size="100"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="100" showname="Frame Length" value="64" size="100"/>
    <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="100" showname="Captured Length" value="64" size="100"/>
    <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Jan 31, 2018 00:47:08.960176000 BDT" showname="Captured Time" value="1517338028.960176000" size="100"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame" showname="Frame 13: 100 bytes on wire (800 bits), 100 bytes captured (800 bits) on interface 0" size="100" pos="0">
    <field name="frame.interface_id" showname="Interface id: 0" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.encap_type" showname="Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture (25)" size="0" pos="0" show="25"/>
    <field name="frame.time" showname="Arrival Time: Jan 31, 2018 00:47:08.960176000 BDT" size="0" pos="0" show="Jan 31, 2018 00:47:08.960176000"/>
    <field name="frame.offset_shift" showname="Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_epoch" showname="Epoch Time: 1517338028.960176000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="1517338028.960176000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_delta" showname="Time delta from previous captured frame: 50.679499000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="50.679499000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 50.679499000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="50.679499000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_relative" showname="Time since reference or first frame: 196.152414000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="196.152414000"/>
    <field name="frame.number" showname="Frame Number: 13" size="0" pos="0" show="13"/>
    <field name="frame.len" showname="Frame Length: 100 bytes (800 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="100"/>
    <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 100 bytes (800 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="100"/>
    <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.ignored" showname="Frame is ignored: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.protocols" showname="Protocols in frame: sll:ip:icmp:data" size="0" pos="0" show="sll:ip:icmp:data"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="sll" showname="Linux cooked capture" size="16" pos="0">
    <field name="sll.pkttype" showname="Packet type: Sent by us (4)" size="2" pos="0" show="4" value="0004"/>
    <field name="sll.hatype" showname="Link-layer address type: 512" size="2" pos="2" show="512" value="0200"/>
    <field name="sll.halen" showname="Link-layer address length: 0" size="2" pos="4" show="0" value="0000"/>
    <field name="sll.etype" showname="Protocol: IP (0x0800)" size="2" pos="14" show="0x0800" value="0800"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="ip" showname="Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.93.65.103 (10.93.65.103), Dst: 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)" size="20" pos="16">
    <field name="ip.version" showname="Version: 4" size="1" pos="16" show="4" value="45"/>
    <field name="ip.hdr_len" showname="Header length: 20 bytes" size="1" pos="16" show="20" value="45"/>
    <field name="ip.dsfield" showname="Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))" size="1" pos="17" show="0" value="00">
      <field name="ip.dsfield.dscp" showname="0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)" size="1" pos="17" show="0x00" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
      <field name="ip.dsfield.ecn" showname=".... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)" size="1" pos="17" show="0x00" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
    </field>
    <field name="ip.len" showname="Total Length: 84" size="2" pos="18" show="84" value="0054"/>
    <field name="ip.id" showname="Identification: 0x0ea5 (3749)" size="2" pos="20" show="0x0ea5" value="0ea5"/>
    <field name="ip.flags" showname="Flags: 0x02 (Don&apos;t Fragment)" size="1" pos="22" show="0x02" value="40">
      <field name="ip.flags.rb" showname="0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set" size="1" pos="22" show="0" value="40"/>
      <field name="ip.flags.df" showname=".1.. .... = Don&apos;t fragment: Set" size="1" pos="22" show="1" value="40"/>
      <field name="ip.flags.mf" showname="..0. .... = More fragments: Not set" size="1" pos="22" show="0" value="40"/>
    </field>
    <field name="ip.frag_offset" showname="Fragment offset: 0" size="2" pos="22" show="0" value="4000"/>
    <field name="ip.ttl" showname="Time to live: 64" size="1" pos="24" show="64" value="40"/>
    <field name="ip.proto" showname="Protocol: ICMP (1)" size="1" pos="25" show="1" value="01"/>
    <field name="ip.checksum" showname="Header checksum: 0xd030 [correct]" size="2" pos="26" show="0xd030" value="d030">
      <field name="ip.checksum_good" showname="Good: True" size="2" pos="26" show="1" value="d030"/>
      <field name="ip.checksum_bad" showname="Bad: False" size="2" pos="26" show="0" value="d030"/>
    </field>
    <field name="ip.src" showname="Source: 10.93.65.103 (10.93.65.103)" size="4" pos="28" show="10.93.65.103" value="0a5d4167"/>
    <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 10.93.65.103 (10.93.65.103)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="28" show="10.93.65.103" value="0a5d4167"/>
    <field name="ip.src_host" showname="Source Host: 10.93.65.103" hide="yes" size="4" pos="28" show="10.93.65.103" value="0a5d4167"/>
    <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 10.93.65.103" hide="yes" size="4" pos="28" show="10.93.65.103" value="0a5d4167"/>
    <field name="ip.dst" showname="Destination: 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)" size="4" pos="32" show="8.8.8.8" value="08080808"/>
    <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="32" show="8.8.8.8" value="08080808"/>
    <field name="ip.dst_host" showname="Destination Host: 8.8.8.8" hide="yes" size="4" pos="32" show="8.8.8.8" value="08080808"/>
    <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 8.8.8.8" hide="yes" size="4" pos="32" show="8.8.8.8" value="08080808"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="icmp" showname="Internet Control Message Protocol" size="64" pos="36">
    <field name="icmp.type" showname="Type: 8 (Echo (ping) request)" size="1" pos="36" show="8" value="08"/>
    <field name="icmp.code" showname="Code: 0" size="1" pos="37" show="0" value="00"/>
    <field name="icmp.checksum" showname="Checksum: 0x5b93 [correct]" size="2" pos="38" show="0x5b93" value="5b93"/>
    <field name="icmp.checksum_bad" showname="Bad Checksum: False" hide="yes" size="2" pos="38" show="0" value="5b93"/>
    <field name="icmp.ident" showname="Identifier (BE): 4058 (0x0fda)" size="2" pos="40" show="4058" value="0fda"/>
    <field name="icmp.ident" showname="Identifier (LE): 55823 (0xda0f)" size="2" pos="40" show="55823" value="0fda"/>
    <field name="icmp.seq" showname="Sequence number (BE): 1 (0x0001)" size="2" pos="42" show="1" value="0001"/>
    <field name="icmp.seq_le" showname="Sequence number (LE): 256 (0x0100)" size="2" pos="42" show="256" value="0001"/>
    <field name="icmp.data_time" showname="Timestamp from icmp data: Jan 31, 2018 00:47:08.000000000 BDT" size="8" pos="44" show="Jan 31, 2018 00:47:08.000000000" value="acbd705a00000000"/>
    <field name="icmp.data_time_relative" showname="Timestamp from icmp data (relative): 0.960176000 seconds" size="8" pos="44" show="0.960176000" value="acbd705a00000000"/>
    <field name="data" value="a2a60e0000000000101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637">
      <field name="data.data" showname="Data: a2a60e0000000000101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f..." size="48" pos="52" show="a2:a6:0e:00:00:00:00:00:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1f:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:2a:2b:2c:2d:2e:2f:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37" value="a2a60e0000000000101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637"/>
      <field name="data.len" showname="Length: 48" size="0" pos="52" show="48"/>
    </field>
  </proto>
</packet>
```

**Scapy Crafted:**

```
9 <packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="54">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="10" showname="Number" value="a" size="54"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="54" showname="Frame Length" value="36" size="54"/>
    <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="54" showname="Captured Length" value="36" size="54"/>
    <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Jan 31, 2018 00:45:47.650839000 BDT" showname="Captured Time" value="1517337947.650839000" size="54"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame" showname="Frame 10: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0" size="54" pos="0">
    <field name="frame.interface_id" showname="Interface id: 0" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.encap_type" showname="Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture (25)" size="0" pos="0" show="25"/>
    <field name="frame.time" showname="Arrival Time: Jan 31, 2018 00:45:47.650839000 BDT" size="0" pos="0" show="Jan 31, 2018 00:45:47.650839000"/>
    <field name="frame.offset_shift" showname="Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_epoch" showname="Epoch Time: 1517337947.650839000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="1517337947.650839000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_delta" showname="Time delta from previous captured frame: 41.557182000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="41.557182000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 41.557182000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="41.557182000"/>
    <field name="frame.time_relative" showname="Time since reference or first frame: 114.843077000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="114.843077000"/>
    <field name="frame.number" showname="Frame Number: 10" size="0" pos="0" show="10"/>
    <field name="frame.len" showname="Frame Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="54"/>
    <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="54"/>
    <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.ignored" showname="Frame is ignored: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.protocols" showname="Protocols in frame: sll:data" size="0" pos="0" show="sll:data"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="sll" showname="Linux cooked capture" size="16" pos="0">
    <field name="sll.pkttype" showname="Packet type: Sent by us (4)" size="2" pos="0" show="4" value="0004"/>
    <field name="sll.hatype" showname="Link-layer address type: 512" size="2" pos="2" show="512" value="0200"/>
    <field name="sll.halen" showname="Link-layer address length: 0" size="2" pos="4" show="0" value="0000"/>
    <field name="sll.ltype" showname="Protocol: Unknown (0x0000)" size="2" pos="14" show="0x0000" value="0000"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="fake-field-wrapper">
    <field name="data" value="0021450000240001000040011f050a5d4167080808080800272b000000003132333435363738">
      <field name="data.data" showname="Data: 0021450000240001000040011f050a5d4167080808080800..." size="38" pos="16" show="00:21:45:00:00:24:00:01:00:00:40:01:1f:05:0a:5d:41:67:08:08:08:08:08:00:27:2b:00:00:00:00:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38" value="0021450000240001000040011f050a5d4167080808080800272b000000003132333435363738"/>
      <field name="data.len" showname="Length: 38" size="0" pos="16" show="38"/>
  </field>
</proto>
</packet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first capture a packet with both Scapy and tshark and see how they look like. Then, try to mimic this packet, send it back (at first, you can try to send the exact packet as you received it) and see how tshark sees it.

An option if that fails is to leave the PPP layer to the host's network stack and use `sr(IP()[...])` rather than `srp(PPP()/IP())` and see if that works. For that, you need to check that the route to your IP destination uses the PPP interface (use `conf.route.route("[IP address]")` to be sure).

Regarding why `sendp` does not work, I think this might be a bug in Scapy. If you are using Linux, could you get the [current development version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), apply the following patch and try again?

```
diff --git a/scapy/arch/linux.py b/scapy/arch/linux.py
index b451fd15..4ad3c82f 100644
--- a/scapy/arch/linux.py
+++ b/scapy/arch/linux.py
@@ -491,7 +491,7 @@ class L3PacketSocket(SuperSocket):

 class L2Socket(SuperSocket):
     desc = "read/write packets at layer 2 using Linux PF_PACKET sockets"
-    def __init__(self, iface=None, type=ETH_P_ALL, promisc=None, filter=None, nofilter=0):
+    def __init__(self, iface=None, type=0, promisc=None, filter=None, nofilter=0):
         self.iface = conf.iface if iface is None else iface
         self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
         self.ins.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 0)
@@ -555,7 +555,7 @@ class L2Socket(SuperSocket):

 class L2ListenSocket(SuperSocket):
     desc = "read packets at layer 2 using Linux PF_PACKET sockets"
-    def __init__(self, iface = None, type = ETH_P_ALL, promisc=None, filter=None, nofilter=0):
+    def __init__(self, iface=None, type=0, promisc=None, filter=None, nofilter=0):
         self.type = type
         self.outs = None
         self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
```

Comment: tried as you advised, sent ping and captured through scapy, and then send the exact captured packet, still tshark is seeing with Ethernet layer added

Comment: >>> pkt
<Sniffed: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:9 Other:0>
>>> pkt[0]
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=84 id=4991 flags=DF frag=0L ttl=64 proto=icmp chksum=0xc1e1 src=10.96.74.217 dst=8.8.8.8 options=[] |<ICMP  type=echo-request code=0 chksum=0xc191 id=0x154c seq=0x1 |<Raw  load='\xd8\xe0nZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x13\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567' |>>>
>>> sendp(pkt[0], iface="ppp0")
.
Sent 1 packets.

Comment: with tshark, for ping packet (sent from command line) the captured packets have 'PPP/IP/ICMP' layer, whereas while sent through scapy tshark sees the captured packets have 'Ethernet/Data' (here the first 14 bytes are treated as Ethernet and rest as unknown protocol)

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, still its not working, if I send a packet like IP()/ICMP()/"Data" with send or sr it doesn't show anything in tshark trace. Am I following the exact way you are showing? Here is the code: 

`code`
>>> newpkt
<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp src=10.103.50.166 dst=8.8.8.8 |<ICMP  |<Raw  load='1234567890' |>>>
>>> send(newpkt,iface="ppp0")
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>> sr(newpkt,iface="ppp0")
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
^C
Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:1 Other:0>)

Comment: Can you check if Scapy's routing table includes the `ppp` route? What is the output of `conf.route` and `conf.route.route('8.8.8.8')`?

Comment: Thanks a million! that worked, i have added the route in conf.route and the packet is traversing with correct link layer protocol (with send/sr). Sorry to miss that part. And if possible pls also let me know the correct way to send the same packet with sendp.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. I have updated my answer. Could you apply the patch and tell me if it works?

Comment: Can you share the output of `tshark -T pdml` for one "real" PPP packet and for one "forged"?

Comment: i have changed both the lines, now tshark is not showing ethernet layer but its not able to show any layer at all. scapy: code>>> pkt = PPP()/IP(src="10.59.184.190", dst="8.8.8.8")/ICMP()/"1234567890" >>> sendp(pkt, iface="ppp0") WARNING: Unable to guess type (interface=ppp0 protocol=0x0 family=512). Using <member 'name' of 'Packet' objects> . Sent 1 packets.code Tshark: [Protocols in frame: sll:data] Linux cooked capture Packet type: Sent by us (4) Link-layer address type: 512 Link-layer address length: 0 Protocol: Unknown (0x0000) Data

Comment: 0000  00 21 45 00 00 26 00 01 00 00 40 01 1a 05 0a 6b   .!E..&....@....k
0010  46 57 08 08 08 08 08 00 ed fa 00 00 00 00 31 32   FW............12
0020  33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30                           34567890

is the initial byte a problem here? for good packets first byte starts with 21

Comment: Please share the output **using `-t pdml`** in your answer, not in a comment, as it is hard to read here.

Comment: tshark output given in my question section.